# sitecore mvc value of droplink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, razor-2, sitecore-mvc

I am looking for the simplest way to get the referenced item value for a droplink field.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Alignment")
```

I want to get the value of the choice, what's the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

The `Droplink` field stores the referenced item's ID.  To retrieve this ID (providing the field is present in your current item/model):

`((LinkField)Model.Item.Fields["Alignment"]).Value`

To output the referenced item's name, you could do something like this:

`@(Model.Item.Database.GetItem(((LinkField)Model.Item.Fields["Alignment"]).Value).Name)`

But that's really ugly.  The preferred approach would be to create an extension method encapsulating some of the above so you're not having to re-type that out :D

The article [Extending the SitecoreHelper Class](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-mvc-playground-part-4-extending-the-sitecorehelper-class) by John West shows how to extend the SitecoreHelper class to add custom field renderers, so you could end up creating a neat re-usable snippet like:

`@(Html.Sitecore().ReferenceField("Alignment","Name"))`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have ability to edit fields of alignment item which is chosen in *'Alignment'* droplink field of context item or just show values of alignment item's fields for visitors:

```
@{
    Sitecore.Data.Fields.ReferenceField alignmentField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Alignment"];
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item alignmentItem = alignmentField.TargetItem;
}

<div>
    @Html.Sitecore().Field("Text of Alignment", alignmentItem)
</div>
```

This example assumes that *Alignment* template contains *'Text of Alignment'* field.

Comment: Key here is that the type is `ReferenceField` instead of `LinkField` as in the previous top-rated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a partial view i.e. .cshtml file you can also use something like below:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.TextField alignment= Model.Item.Fields["Alignment"];
```

This will give you the id of the set item in the drop link , then from that id can retrieve it from the database like:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(alignment.Value))
{
    var setAlignment = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(alignment.Value);
    if (setAlignment != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(setAlignment.Name))
    {
     setAlignment.Name
    }
}
```

Personally i prefer this way as i can check if the droplink is set before trying to use the value.